# Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame Sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am looking for a way to sort a column in a DataFrame with multiple index levels. In my DataFrame index level 0 is state name ("STNAME") and index level 1 is city name ("CTYNAME").

My initial DataFrame looks like this:

In:

```
df = census_df
df = df.set_index(["STNAME" ,"CTYNAME"])
df = df.loc[: ,["CENSUS2010POP"]]
print(df.head())
```

Out:

```
                           CENSUS2010POP
STNAME  CTYNAME 
Alabama Alabama            4779736
        Autauga County     54571
        Baldwin County     182265
        Barbour County     27457
        Bibb County        22915
```

However, when I try to apply sorting to "CENSUS2010POP" column it ruins all the hierarchy:

In:

```
df = census_df
df = df.set_index(["STNAME" ,"CTYNAME"])
df = df.loc[: ,["CENSUS2010POP"]]
df = df.sort_values("CENSUS2010POP")
print (df.head())
```

Out:

```
                                CENSUS2010POP
STNAME        CTYNAME   
Texas         Loving County     82
Hawaii        Kalawao County    90
Texas         King County       286
Kenedy        County            416
Nebraska      Arthur County     460
```

I am wondering if there's a way to sort column and index levels

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `STNAME` to the `sort_values`

```
df.sort_values(['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP'])
```

On random data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'STNAME':[0]*4+[1]*4,
    'CTYNAME':[0,1,2,3]*2,
    'CENSUS2010POP':np.random.randint(10,100,8)
}).set_index(['STNAME', 'CTYNAME'])
```

Output is:

```
                CENSUS2010POP
STNAME CTYNAME               
0      3                   19
       1                   22
       0                   47
       2                   82
1      1                   15
       3                   74
       0                   85
       2                   89
```